# docker instance bridge with 9000 port, use 127.0.0.1:9000 can connect but 192.168.1.145:9000 connect fail,why?

Tags: docker, networking

I use one cloudy server with two ether card,like this [image],and i have run one docker instance with net bridge, listen on 9000;like this [image]
but now I can visite with http://127.0.0.1:9000 ,but can't visit with http://192.168.1.145:9000 like this [image] . then I use another server at the same local network, [image]
at that server ,I can visite with http://192.168.1.145:9000 ;[image]
I don't know why? and I hope somebody can resole question. thank you!

Comment: Please don't attach screen shots of terminal windows to SO questions.  Please rewrite this question with a description in text of what's going wrong, what specific error you're getting, and the minimum application source code necessary to demonstrate the issue.  Low-level diagnostic output like `ifconfig` or `ping` probably isn't necessary.

Comment: sorry, I worried  my english can't demonstrate this question,so upload those screen shots.  I have server with two network card ,I deploy one docker container web site with bridge network ; host listen on port 9000; but I can visit this site with http://127.0.0.1:9000,but can't visit with http://192.168.1.145:9000 at this server (ip:192.168.1.145). but I can visit this site with http://192.168.1.145:9000 at another server at the same network.

Comment: docker command : `docker  run --name testweb3 --restart=always -p 9000:9002  -d -v /opt/dockerInstance/testWeb3/1.0_21:/opt/dockerInstance/testWeb3/1.0_21  -w /opt/dockerInstance/testWeb3/1.0_21 mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 dotnet /opt/dockerInstance/testWeb3/1.0_21/testweb3.dll`